# graph-tool: How to save Property maps elements in the graphml?

Tags: python-2.7, graph-tool, graphml

It is my first attempt to use graph-tools with python.
I have a graph with some important information in Properties Maps (names, topics,...).

When I save the graph using `g.save("test.graphml")`, the Property Map related information is not saved: there is just vertices and edges.

I couldn't find a way to save that information as well. 
Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make property maps internal. See this link:

https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#internal-property-maps